# ARIMA model with non significiant coefficients

Tags: arima

I am confused with ARIMA modelling. My results are as below:

```
Parameters  Estimates of coefficients   Standard Error  P-value
ma1         0.057338                    0.019720        0.00364
intercept   0.000851                    0.000498        0.08744
```

It seems that intercept term is not significant at level 0.05. So do I accept the model as:

y<sub>t</sub>=0.000851 + 0.057338e<sub>t-1</sub> + e<sub>t</sub>

or

y<sub>t</sub>=0.057338e<sub>t-1</sub> + e<sub>t</sub>

or

Do I need to re-estimate the ma coefficient with constraint intercept=0.

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you know that the MA(1) model is best whether or not you include an intercept?  What does your correlation structure look like?

Comment: I studied the models with intercept. Among these models I choose ma(1) model according to AIC and BIC criterions. Now, I will study models without intercep as Hamid701 suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I suggest is to re-fit your model as a ARIMA(0,0,1) and remove the intercept while fitting your data to the model, for example if you are fitting your model in R, the function *Arima()* allows you to do that.

```
fit <- Arima(Data, order=c(0,0,1), include.mean=FALSE)
```

Comment: That would be the right thing to do if a first order MA model is the best ARIMA model and satisfies the diagnostic tests.

Comment: yes exactly, I assumed he is applying the methodology of Box and Jenkins, so he will come to the diagnostic part as soon as he fits his model.